# Community Wiki editing badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, community-wiki, badge-request

Community wiki posts earn no reputation (except for 2 points per edit for new users) and only the original author gets the question/ answer badges for them. So I wondered how to encourage wiki editing and few badge proposals occurred:

- Wikipedian (bronze) - edited a CW answer at least [two days old] that got [125%] of its original score (minimum [3] + original score) between this and next edit
- Wiki Expert (silver) - edited a CW answer at least [two days old] that got [150%] of its original score (minimum [10] + original score) between this and next edit
- Wiki Guru (gold) - edited a CW answer at least [two days old] that got [200%] of its original score (minimum [40] + original score) between this and next edit
- Wiki Necromancer (silver) - edited a CW answer in a question with no activity for at least [30] days that got [110%] of its original score (minimum [5] + original score) between this and next edit
- Wiki Reversal (gold) - edited a CW answer with score of [-3] or worse which got score of [20] or better later

These badges have a common prerequisite: system must know somehow the score at the time of an edit (not sure how easy/ hard is this to implement).

The goal is clear: to encourage good community wiki edits, especially on answers that are old and unlikely to be noticed and improved (Wiki Necromancer) or bad (Wiki Reversal).

Perhaps not for Wiki Reversal, but for other badges there is some risk of gaming the system. There are CW answers that would get upvotes regardless of how marginal (or even bad) the edit is, but they tend to be new and/or with high score already. This is the aim of some starting time before edits qualify for this badge and of percentage of the original score earned until the next edit. If the user manages to make a bad edit that gets the badge either, then OK, but such betting shouldn't earn any badge most of the time and never silver or golden one.
I guess very few users wouldn't edit a CW answer of sheer malice to assure someone else wouldn't get an extra badge.

*Example: the answer has score of 32 when edited, so it must achieve score of 40 (32 + 32/4 = 32 + 8) to get Wikipedian badge, 48 (32 + 32/2 = 32 + 16) to get Wiki Expert and 72 (32 + 32 is less than 32 + 40) to get Wiki Guru.*

The badges will be earned when the requirements are met - if there's no more edit needed, it's OK.

Disclaimer: all values in [brackets] are just first guess. Current wording is not meant as a dogma, and should be changed if not clear.

EDIT: as [this blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) suggests, CW is intended for answers primarily. So I changed my proposal to CW answers - edits on CW questions are rarely so wanted as those in (some) CW answers.

Comment: Or just remove community wiki completely...

Comment: Community wiki does seem to have become largely used as a punishment state for excessive editing which is a sad state of affairs

Comment: @Richard Tingle: [That changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947) somewhat later, in the beginning of 2014.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Community wiki posts earn no reputation (except for 2 points per edit for new users) and only the original author gets the question/ answer badges for them. So I wondered how to encourage wiki editing and few badge proposals occurred

One thing that is missing from your proposal is "Why do we want to encourage editing of CW posts?"  What behavior are you trying to encourage, or why benefit is the community going to get from editing CW posts?

In my opinion, the 2 point rep award for <2k users and the existing badges is enough motivation to edit posts.  We don't need more badges encouraging people to make edits, as enough people game the system to get the rep and the other editing badges.

And since a high percentage of CW posts are old posts, you'll end up with people bumping a bunch of posts that we don't necessarily want on the front page just to get a badge.  The reason we don't necessarily want them on the front page is many represent a class of question is no longer a good fit for the site.  Every so often you have someone who gets a question closed saying "why did my question get closed when this *(4 year old)* question had 500 upvotes", so it might encourage more of these out of scope questions and more whining on meta about "legitimate programming" posts getting closed.

So back to my original question "Why do we want to encourage editing of CW posts?".  The way I see it, there is almost no benefit beyond what the system already provides.